# Buscar una letra dentro de una palabra

Tags: python

Ayuda, en python tengo que ingresar una palabra y una letra, después identificar en dónde se encuentra la letra y desplegar cada letra de la palabra

por ejemplo
Ingrese palabra: charlar,
Letra a buscar: a,
Resultado busqueda: _ _ a _ _ a _

Lo que llevo de código es esto, pero aún no encuentro solución para buscar la letra

```
string = input("Ingrese una palabra: ")

letra = input("Ingrese la letra que desea buscar: ")

if letra in string:

  repeat = ["-"]*len(string)

  print("".join(repeat))

else:

  print("La letra que ingreso no se encuentra dentro del string")
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un `ciclo-for` para cada carácter y filtrar con una condición `if`, si es igual a la letra que buscas entonces muestras esa, sino muestras "_"

Comment: `salida = ''.join(letra if x == 'a' else '_' for x in palabra)`

Answer (score 0):

Te explico mi solución y a continuación te adjunto el código:

1. Pido la palabra. Ejemplo -> *palabra*
2. Pido la letra a buscar. Ejemplo -> *a*
3. Creo un string auxiliar (`s=''`) en el que guardaré mis resultados.
4. Recorro la palabra.

- Si encuentro la letra a buscar, añado a mi string auxiliar s, la letra
- Si no, añado a mi string auxiliar '_'

```
string = input("Ingrese una palabra: ")

letra = input("Ingrese la letra que desea buscar: ")

s = ''

for i in string:
    if i == letra:

      s += i

    else:

      s += ' _ '
    
print(s)
```